# CAPSULE EXCEPTION when trying to run multiple corda nodes

Tags: corda

I'm deploying two Corda nodes to a production server following [this official guide](https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.9/community/deploying-a-node.html). I used `systemd` to manage the two node services. After I've successfully started one node, another node cannot start with the error:

```
CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Could not initialize cache directory ./capsule while processing attribute Native-Dependencies: {} (for stack trace, run with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)
```

The guide seems to warn about the issue in the beginning, but the same issue still occurs despite using the recommended configuration.

What is the right systemd configuration to run multiple nodes on the same server?

EDIT: this issue actually has nothing with the parallel run of Corda nodes. The error occurred because the node has no write permission in the running directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the systemd config from the linked guide:

```
[Unit]
Description=Corda Node - Bank of Breakfast Tea
Requires=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=corda
WorkingDirectory=/opt/corda
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/corda/corda.jar
Restart=on-failure
Environment="CAPSULE_CACHE_DIR=./capsule"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For multiple nodes you need different values for both, the `WorkingDirectory` and the `Environment` (CAPSULE_CACHE_DIR) directories.

Another `User` and `Description` do not hurt either.

Comment: Hi Nils. I've changed the working directory to `/opt/corda1` and the capsule directory to `/.capsule1`. The same problem still occurs: `CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Could not initialize cache directory ./capsule1 while processing attribute Native-Dependencies: {}`.

Comment: Hi @McXD , maybe there is a permission issue if the dirs are not colliding. Make sure that the corda user has write access in the designated directories.